# Import scene into VSE with different camera size

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I am preparing a video in 1920x1080. This is a presentation style video, meaning it has some slides and some images. Some of those images are  direct renders from blender, but instead of rendering into an image and then importing, I am just adding a scene strip into the video.

However, the render camera in the scene is in portrait format and when I insert the scene into the video, everything gets squashed like in the image

Is there any way to fix this? Do I have to use a 1920x1080 in the render scene?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a Transform Effect strip and adjust the settings to fit, however, this can be a tedious process, so here is a script that will simplify the process:

1. First, run or install this script:
   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tin2tin/blender-reset-aspect-ratio/master/reset-aspect-ratio.py
2. Add a transform strip to your strip that needs rescaling.
3. Select the Transform strip.
4. In the Sidebar find the Reset Aspect Ratio and click it.

[image]